# EditText android:maxLength escribir hasta 10 caracteres

Tags: java, android

El tema es el siguiente , tengo un EditText

```
 <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txtBeneficiary"
                android:inputType="phone"
                android:maxLength="10"
                android:layout_width="160dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:textSize="@dimen/simple_text_size"
                android:textColor="@color/light_grey"/>
```

Claramente te deja escribir hasta 10 caracteres ,

Pero yo en mi aplicacion tengo un boton el cual te trae los contactos y podes elegir uno , cuando elegis muestro el nombre envez el numero y me gaurdo ese numero para despues , el problema viene en que si el nombre es mas largo de 10 me queda el nombre cortado , tengo alguna forma de sacarle la restriccion momentaneamente ? o existe una forma optima de hacer esto sin tener que sacarle la restriccion 
 [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Quieres que solo permita escribir 10 caracteres?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para que permita traer una longitud mayor a 10 caracteres debes eliminar la restricción:

```
android:maxLength="10"
```

Pero puedes agregar un filtro que permita escribir únicamente 10 caracteres, pero antes definirlo es importante escribir el nombre para que se visualice completo.

```
    InputFilter[] FilterArray = new InputFilter[1];
    FilterArray[0] = new InputFilter.LengthFilter(10);
    myEditText.setFilters(FilterArray);
```

Comment: Si la idea es que solo puedan escribir 10 pero por ejemplo si eligen uno de los contactos que si deje poner mas de 10 para que asi por ejemplo no se corte un nombre de contacto ,